# Linux: how to change maximum number of files a process can open?

Tags: linux, sockets, operating-system, system, ulimit

I have to execute a process on a cluster of machines. Size of cluster is of order 100. So I cannot execute processes manually, I have to execute them by script(which uses ssh, currently I am using python-paramiko for this). Number of tcp sockets these processes open is more than 1024(default limit of linux.) So I need to change that using {ulimit -n 10000}. This makes the changes for that shell session only. And this command works only with root user. So my script is not able to do that. 
I tried to execute this command

```
sudo su && ulimit -n 10000 && <commandToExecuteMyProcess>
```

But this didn't work. The commands after "sudo su" didn't execute at all. They execute only when I logout of the su session.
[This](http://blog.intelligencecomputing.io/infra/8623/origin-how-to-make-ulimit-values-permanent) article shows way to make the changes permanently. But when I open limits.conf, I didn't find anything there. It only has some commented notes.

Please suggest me some way to increase the limit permanently or change it by script for each session.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works: `sudo su` just opens a new shell so you can introduce commands as root, and after you exit that shell it executes the rest of the line as normal user.

Second: your this is a special case because `ulimit` is not actually a program, but a bash shell built-in command, so it must be used within bash, that is why something like `sudo ulimit -n 10000` won't work: `sudo` can't find that program because it doesn't exist.

So, the only alternative is a bit ugly but works:

```
 sudo bash -c 'ulimit -n 10000 && <command>'
```

Everything inside `'...'` will execute in a bash session of the root user.

Note that you can replace `&&` with `;` in this case: that's because it is being executed as root and `ulimit -n 10000` will always complete successfully.